# Using TcpClient/TcpListener, what is the best method to receive an unknown amount of separate messages?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

My current `ClientHandler` method receives a `TcpClient`, opens up a `NetStream` on said client, and starts pulling data from it like this:

```
                try
            {
                //byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize]; 
                byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
                int bytes_read = netstream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Bytes Read");

                while ( bytes_read > 0)
                {
                    memstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes_read);
                    bytes_read = netstream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    if (memstream.Length > 255)
                    {
                        MemStreamRead(memstream);
                        memstream.Flush();
                        OkResponse(netstream);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No longer connected");
                connected = false;
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
```

I can already get the first message out of the Client, but I'm having a hard time thinking of how I'm going to keep the stream open for new messages, and deciding when my current message is done.

`netstream.DataAvailable` seems like it could work, I'm assuming it detects when the `netstream` is no longer getting more data, and returns false. But how do I start listening again once new data is available?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: use an async task with a streamreader to continously read the basestream object of the tcpclient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the `TcpClient` object and its `netstream` somewhere you can use it over and over again. Then call `netstream.Read()` (non-blocking) as often as needed. `DataAvailable` will tell you when there is data to read.

Notice: incoming TCP data is added to a big buffer and can't be separated back into packets as it was received.
Calling `Read()` with sufficient large size will get 'all' data from the buffer.
You will need your own higher-level protocol to separate it. Easy to implement...

On UDP on the other hand, `Read()` will return the data of 1 packet. Following `Read()`s will return next packet's data. The packet-wise 'structure' is retained.

For the TCP higher-level protocol, you could do:

- Start each message (message per *your* definition, could have 1 byte or 100.000 bytes in length) with 1 or more 0xFF bytes, so you can easily detect the message start.
- Start it with 0x02 (STX, has the meaning 'Start of text'), end it with 0x03 (ETX, end of text), so you can exclude 'nonsense' data (e.g. alive messages) that are not surrounded by STX,ETX.
- If you're sending binary data that could include 0x02, 0x03, 0xFF, then you could start each message with nnnnnn, which is a number and defines the message length in bytes. Nonsense data cannot be separated here.

**Edit**:
Further notice:
If the connection is closed by the remote side, `Read()` will still be executed successfully, but not return data. You'll have to find out in another way whether the connection is about to be closed. See my answers on other SO networking questions for more helpful info.

Comment: You may also want to mention that with TCP, calling `.Read` may also only get *part* of a packet too.  Sometimes you need to do multiple `.Read`s to get a complete message.

Comment: @Bradley Uffner: true, although very rare. Packet fragmentation doesn't happen often anymore, and afaik, although MTU is at 1500bytes normally, you'll hardly retrieve incomplete packets from the NIC's input buffer even if the sent data exceeds MTU a lot, like 10kB. TCP layer should reassemble it before passing it further.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I start listening again once new data is available?

Call `Read` again. This is how most loops work, simply call a non-blocking `Read` (or a blocking `Read` on a dedicated thread) and when you get data, process it.

> when my current message is done

That's another problem you have. Your message isn't necessarily done when there's no more data in the OS socket buffer, it's done when it's done as defined by your rules. You typically open the message with a message length, then keep asking the OS for data until you filled a buffer of the given length (or fail due to a timeout).